# Create objects dynamically when knowing part of classname in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am using an external DLL which has an abstract baseclass Packet and subclasses to Packet.

The subclasses are named after the number they represent, one name could be P132_RandomString. I am parsing a file containing these numbers and for each number I want to create a corresponding object. There are hundreds of different subclasses and the DLL have no factory method (at least not for my input).

The problem is I don't know the "RandomString" part, if I did I could have used Reflection but I assume there is no way to use Reflection since I only know the beginning of the classname?

The only solution I could think of is implementing my own factory method with hundreds of case statements but this feels a bit cumbersome...

My question is: is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LINQ Where clause to grab the type you want.
Consider the following program:
(This assumes you know the base class and the prefix)

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {

        string prefix = "p22";
        IEnumerable<Type> types = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll").GetTypes();    
        Type baseClass = typeof(foo);
        Type foundType = types.Where(
            t => t.Name.StartsWith( prefix ) &&
                t.IsSubclassOf( baseClass )
                ).SingleOrDefault();
        foo myClass = (foo)Activator.CreateInstance( foundType );
                //Do Stuff with myClass 
    }
}
abstract class foo { }
class p22_notMyClass { }
class p22_myclass : foo { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to use Assembly.LoadFrom to load the assembly file, but apart from that foundType gets null unless I remove t.IsSubClassOf( baseClass ) which is weird... Once I remove that I get the correct type but then I can't cast to the abstract class foo "InvalidCastException".

Comment: Update: It now works using Assembly.LoadFrom, the reason it didn't work first was that I referenced a copy of the DLL... And I got different contexts. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

To load all types from assembly use `Assembly.GetTypes`

```
 var objects = new List<Object>();
 Assembly SampleAssembly;
 SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
 // Obtain a reference to types known to exist in assembly.
 Type[] types = SampleAssembly.GetTypes();
 foreach(Type t in types)
    if(t.Name.StartsWith("P132")
       objects.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t));
```

Use `Activator.CreateInstance` method described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) + some `String.IndexOf` (or other matching) on `Type.FullName + Activator.CreateInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Assembly.GetTypes()` method and iterate the types and find out which class has the number in its name. Then you can use Activator.CreateInstance to get an instance.